# Setting the IndependentRangeAxis in XAML for chart with multiple series and two Y axis

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

In my chart I have defined three axes, one X and two Y.

```
<Axis x:Name="PercentageAxis" Orientation="Y" [...] /> 
<Axis x:Name="NormalAxis" Orientation="Y"[...] />
<Axis [...] />
```

And several series.

```
<LineSeries .... />
<LineSeries .... />
<LineSeries .... />
<LineSeries .... />
```

I would like to be able to assign a series to a specific Axis like so:

```
<LineSeries DependentRangeAxis='PercentageAxis' [...] />
```

because most of the series will be plotted against the normal Y axis while only a few will be plotted against the percentage axis. How do I do this binding in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Element name binding, in your example you would use:-

```
 <LineSeries DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=PercentageAxis}" [...] />
```

BTW, Your `Axis` are actually `LinearAxis` though and are listed in the charts `Axes` property right?